# Relation between length of arc of horocycle and length of chord?

Tags: reference-request, hyperbolic-geometry, reference-works

In Hyperbolic geometry:

What is the relation between the length of the arc of a horocycle between two points and the length of the chord (segment) between the two points?

Also what is the relation between the length of the arc of a horocycle between two points and the maximum distance  between the chord (segment) and the horocycle?

Also what is the relation between the length of the arc of a horocycle between two points and the angle between the chord (segment) and the radius of the horocycle?

In short I am just looking for some formula's that can tell me more about arcs of horocycles.

references to formularia very welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some hints about how to do this constructively. Suppose $p,q$ are points in the hyperbolic plane such that the length of the arc of the horocycle between $p,q$ is equal to $\ell$. Then we may assume that, in the upper half plane, $p=(0,1)$ and $q=(\ell,1)$.

To get a formula for the length of the geodesic segment between $p,q$, construct a semicircle through $p,q$ hitting the real line at right angles, and integrate the arc length element $\frac{ds}{y}$ along $C$ from $p$ to $q$.

To compute the maximum distance: integrate the arc length element along the vertical segment from $(\ell/2,1)$ up to the point where that vertical segment hits $C$.

And the angle you ask for is just the ordinary Euclidean angle between the circle $C$ and the line $y=1$ at the point $p$.

Comment: thanks , funny the angle is easiest discribed in the poincare disk model :) , but any idea for a formularium of formula'sfor the hyperbolic plane?

Comment: You might want to read up on trigonometry in the hyperbolic plane. Good sources are Ratcliffe's book, or the book of Thurston and Levy. Although the hyperbolic trig formulas in those sources do not say much about horocycles, it is easy enough to compute lengths of horocycles by throwing your problem into the upper half plane and your horocycle onto the line $y=1$ where horocycle length equals Euclidean length.